# How to send POST response to another function using React.js and axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have `fileUploadHandler` function as below that POST the file.
The response of post would look like: `{ filename: '123sdfg.xlsx' }`

```
fileUploadHandler = (fileData) => {
    const formData1 = new FormData();
    formData1.append("file", fileData)
    postFileUpload(formData1).then((result) => console.log("response", result.data));    
  };
```

I tried below code, but throws error that storeFile undefined.

```
fileUploadHandler = (fileData) => {
    const formData1 = new FormData();
    formData1.append("file", fileData)
    postFileUpload(formData1).then((result) => storeFile(result.data)); 
    storeFile;
  };
```

post call function looks as below:

```
export const postFileUpload = (values) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios    
    .post('<URL>', values)
    .then((result) => {
      if (result) {
        resolve(result);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      reject({ message: "Error:" + error.message });
    });
  });
}
```

I want handler not only to post file, but get response, and send the response to a another function.
How to return the response from fileUploadHandler to another function like formSubmit (an example).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for. You also might need to add a header specifying the content type if you want to send files using axios.

```
const fileUploadHandler = fileData => {
  const formData1 = new FormData()
  formData1.append("file", fileData)

  axios
    .post("<URL>", formData, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    })
    .then(result => {
      if (result) {
        postFileUpload(result)
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Handle any errors if the upload fails
      console.log(error)
    })
}

const postFileUpload = result => {
  // This will be called after the file is uploaded.
  console.log(result)
}
```

EDIT:

```
const postFileUpload = formData => {
  return axios.post("<URL>", formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  })
}

const fileUploadHandler = fileData => {
  const formData1 = new FormData()
  formData1.append("file", fileData)

  postFileUpload(formData1)
    .then(result => {
      console.log("response", result.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Handle any errors if the upload fails
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: No. I do not want to combine the postFileUpload into fileUploadHandler and these 2 functions are in 2 differents folders. What I want something like below, but it throws error that storeFile not defined.                                  
`fileUploadHandler = (fileData) => {
    const formData1 = new FormData();
    formData1.append("file", fileData)
    postFileUpload(formData1).then((result) => storeFile(result.data));        
    storeFile  };`

Comment: Please see the edit I made to question. The second block code is what I tried but throws error. I want a const like storeFile to be returned by the fileUploadHandler function.